# Why do we need to access the custom Event data through 'detail' Object in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Why do we need to access the custom event property through 'detail' object?

```
function handleMessage(event) {

    alert(event.detail.text); // why do we need to access 'text' property from 'detail' object?

}



// In the Child component, we are using this function to dispatch the custom event with some data.

    function sayHello() {
        dispatch('message', {
            text: 'Hello!'  // we are not wrapping the data into the 'detail' object
        });
    }
```

[Sample code is here](https://svelte.dev/repl/0fe337d16dc546439f870ed33183ae75?version=3.16.4)

Comment: This is not specific to svelte. The `CustomEvent` model supports the `detail` property for passing data. See [Creating Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: Agree. In native custom events we will be using 'detail' object explicitly. But here we are sending the data without wrapping it into 'detail' object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because dispatch is just a wrapper around the DOM CustomEvent Object.
Heres the code which returns an dispatch function from the svelte repo.

```
export function createEventDispatcher() {
    const component = get_current_component();

    return (type: string, detail?: any) => {
        const callbacks = component.$$.callbacks[type];

        if (callbacks) {
            // TODO are there situations where events could be dispatched
            // in a server (non-DOM) environment?
            const event = custom_event(type, detail);
            callbacks.slice().forEach(fn => {
                fn.call(component, event);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see in the function below it has a signature which takes the second argument named as detail, whatever you pass as a second param it will be detail always. its a javascript thing.

```
export function custom_event<T=any>(type: string, detail?: T) {
    const e: CustomEvent<T> = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    e.initCustomEvent(type, false, false, detail);
    return e;
}
```